# Calling File Functions in PHP with a Handle of a Filename

Tags: php, security

From *19 Deadly Sins of Software Security*;

---

> The following code is the poster child for the file-access race condition defect. In between the call to access(2) and open(2), the operating system could switch away from your running process and give another process a time slice. In the interveneing time, the file /tmp/splat could be deleted, and then the application crashes.

```
    …
    const char *filename="/tmp/splat";
    if (access(filename, R_OK)==0) {
      int fd=open(filename, O_RDONLY);
      handle_file_contents(fd);
      close(fd);
    }
```

---

and

---

> Again, this code is accessing the file using a filename. The code determines if the file is readable by the effective user of the Perl script and if it is, reads it. This sinful code is similar to the C/C++ code: between the file check and the read, the file may have disappeared.

```
    #!/user/bin/perl
    my $file="$ENV{HOME}/.config";
    read_config($file) if -r $file;
```

---

and finally,

---

> Use a file handle, not the filename, to verify the file exists and then open it.

```
    $!/ur/bin/perl
    my $file="$ENV{HOME}/.config";
    if (open(FILE, "< $file")) {
      read_config(*FILE) if is_accessible(*FILE);
    }
```

---

The point is that if you use a filename for each call to a file-related function, the file could be changed, deleted, etc. between calls, particularly on a remote server. It’s better to use a file handle or file descriptor. Unfortunately, the PHP manual seems to indicate that most file functions only work on a string representing the filename and don’t have overloads that can take a handle instead, `filesize` in particular:

```
  $fn = "somefile.txt"
  $fh = fopen($fn);
  if ($fh !== FALSE) {
    $data = fread($fh, filesize($fn));
  }
```

That’s not good; between the call to `fopen` and `filesize`, the file could have been altered. Worse, the file could have been altered between the call to `filesize` and the meat of `fread`!

Does anyone know of a way to use PHP file functions, especially `filesize` with handles instead of filenames?

Comment: Unless you're in a secure environment, the issues raised above are of no major concern, particularly in PHP. The race conditions above are all on the local file system - if an attacker has access to the local FS, they can get at your raw PHP code and extract whatever they want anyways.

Comment: To a degree yes, but it depends on the setup. (`fopen` can access more than just local files.) An attacker could also exploit a vulnerability on a shared host. Besides, it’s not even just necessarily attackers that could be the problem (although one would think that a call to `flock` should be sufficient to handle legitimate changes to the file).

Comment: True, but if you're using url handlers in the f*() calls, then you're welcome to any pain caused by attackers fiddling with the remote files - you couldn't use standard defensive programming, such as `flock()`, on the remote files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the data you're looking for can be accessed with [fstat()](http://www.php.net/fstat).

The following can be derived from an fstat() call. See [stat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) for more about the information fstat() returns. From the PHP manual:

```
Array
(
    [dev] => 771
    [ino] => 488704
    [mode] => 33188
    [nlink] => 1
    [uid] => 0
    [gid] => 0
    [rdev] => 0
    [size] => 1114
    [atime] => 1061067181
    [mtime] => 1056136526
    [ctime] => 1056136526
    [blksize] => 4096
    [blocks] => 8
)
```

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick… I have to wait seven minutes before accepting… :-|

Comment: No worries. Glad I could be of (quick) help.